# Creating a feed - create dedicated table or use a view?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I need to build a feed for an initial set of 3 underlying tables, yet more may come later.

As far as I can see I have two options:

1. Create a MySQL view of a union of the 3 tables (or do a union at run time), access this via it's own model.

Or...

2. When I save a row to an underlying table, also save a row to a `feed` table that has a polymorphic relation to one of the 3 underlying tables.

Which would be the best performance wise?

Comment: If you have 3 tables and more to come and you are unioning I don't see what you gain by having a view over a select (with unions)  add more tables and you have to edit the view (or select) I don't understand your second option at all but you would still have to change when more tables come along..BTW why 3 tables when they all have the same format??

Comment: Please provide the CREATEs for both approaches, plus the SELECT that you are concerned about.